# Javascript php validation, form submiting on the second time submit after filling one text box out of 2 textboxes

Tags: javascript, php, validation

Im trying php javascript form validation. There are 2 input fields. And all the 2 fields are manditory. For the first time javascript validation is working and form is not submiting, but when i fill the one text box value of validation error , then the form is submiting without validation.

Here is the html code

```
    <form method="post" name="form_register" id="form_register" action=""  onSubmit="return formValidation();">
        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="<?=$_POST['firstname']?>" size="25"> 
        <input id="lastname" value="<?=$_POST['lastname']?>" name="lastname" type="text" size="25">
```

javascript code :

```
function formValidation()  
{


    var firstname= document.forms["form_register"]["firstname"].value;
    if (firstname===null || firstname==="")
    {
       alert("First name must be filled out");
       document.getElementById('firstname').focus();
       return false;

    }
    var lastname = document.forms["form_register"]["lastname"].value;
        if(lastname  === null || lastname ==="")
         {
              alert("Last name must be filled out");
              document.getElementById('lastname').focus();
             return false;
         }
        else
            {
         return true;
                }
}
```

Php code after form submit :

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
       //insertion goes here
}
```

For the first time i have not entered in the text fields.
result : validation is working.

for the second time submit i have filled only first text box
result : form submitted without checking the second input validation

Comment: Did you removed space on this line too?? 


document.getElementById('lastname ').focus();

Comment: yes i have removed @aejey

Comment: Is it working now? did you tried the exact code i have pasted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an additional space that you have put on the javascript for the name of lastname.

That is you put "lastname " instead of "lastname"

That is what causing the validation (javascript function) to fail after executing that line.

Try this code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">        
        function formValidation()  
{


    var firstname= document.forms["form_register"]["firstname"].value;
    var lastname = document.forms["form_register"]["lastname"].value;

    if (firstname===null || firstname==="")
    {
       alert("First name must be filled out");
       document.getElementById('firstname').focus();
       return false;

    }
    else if(lastname  === null || lastname ==="")
         {
              alert("Last name must be filled out");
              document.getElementById('lastname').focus();
             return false;
         }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}</script>

<form method="post" name="form_register" id="form_register" action=""  onSubmit="return formValidation();">
        <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" value="<?=$_POST['firstname']?>" size="25"> 
        <input id="lastname" value="<?=$_POST['lastname']?>" name="lastname" type="text" size="25">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: removed space and tried but still the form is submitting

Comment: Put it inside if else like what I shown in the code. Please try the code that I have pasted. I have tested it and is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space inside the quotes in your javascript code follow "lastname" on these two lines:

```
    var lastname = document.forms["form_register"]["lastname "].value;

          document.getElementById('lastname ').focus();
```

This could be your problem.

Comment: removed space and tried but still form is submiting.im not able to guess where the code goes wrong